# Webdriver PhantomJS full-page screenshot, work around using PIL?

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, python-imaging-library

My script uses PhantomJS to take full-page screenshots of reports generated via ajax for many different pages with the same report structure, but different data. These reports are black and white and vary in length, but have the same width making it difficult for me to change the window size on webdriver to accomplish the same desired screenshot for all reports. PhantomJS did a great job of saving these png's to the exact length required an no more.

With PhantomJS being deprecated, I have gotten a little creative for finding a patch for my script that yields the same full-page screenshot that PhantomJS offered.

Here is what I got using headless firefox, selenium, PIL->Image.

Is it fast? Not even close. Does it work for what I need it to do? Sure.

```
    # 1120 is fixed report width
    # 5000 is a gross overestimate of 'longest' report
    driver.set_window_size(1120, 5000)
    driver.get(url_of_report)
    driver.save_screenshot('report.png')

    im = Image.open('report.png')
    width, height = im.size

    # // auto round down
    # find the middle of the image due to some padding on the report edges
    x = int(im.size[0] // 2)
    # total length of image
    y = int(im.size[1])


    # for loop, starts at bottom center of image, using getpizel until border is found
    for pixels in range(1, y):
            L_im = im.convert('L')
            z = y - pixels
            k = L_im.getpixel((x, z))
            # report has a bottom border that is always black => 0
            # the space between that border is white => 255
            # if I find black, k is 0 then I know the report ends at that pixel       
            if k == 0:
                print('The length of the report is {}.'.format(z))
                break

    # use newly found z to crop report perfectly
    imgCropped = im.crop((0, 0, im.size[0], im.size[1] - z)) 
    imgCropped.save(filename)
```

So my question is this, is there a more efficient way to get my desired outcome (same full page screenshot offered by PhantomJS)?

Perhaps a more efficient method of getting this same result?

Maybe something far simpler that I am probably overcomplicating?

Comment: I would set the size of the window to match the size of the document. This way you won't have to iterate the pixels and crop the image.

Comment: Florent- I would if I could find a way to get the length of the AJAX generated report. Sadly they vary wildly between ~500px to ~3000px in height. Which is why I over shoot it and then work back to the border to find the height.

Comment: to get the expected height of the window call `driver.execute_script("return window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight + document.body.scrollHeight")`